# FTP response code 552: "Disk full" on upload

Tags: ftp

I'm using FileZilla off and on to upload files to my website, which is hosted by Bluehost. Since a couple of hours I can't upload anything anymore; keep getting response code 552: disk full. I was on chat with their tech support for almost two hours, but we didn't find the cause for the error, less a solution.

**The facts**
I can connect to the server
I can list directories
I can download files
I can rename files
I can delete files
I can move files
Only thing I can't is upload, no matter the file size
I have not used my quota
Problem persists after disconnect/reconnect
Problem shows on another PC (both Windows) as well
Problem also shows with another FTP client (WinSCP)

Any ideas about the cause, and a possible solution?

**Edit**
The most obvious cause would indeed be a full disk. But:
The tech support person could upload a file
The problem persisted after I deleted 100 MB worth
No other customers reported the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a server problem.   My guess is that the Bluehost server you are on has run out of disk. (Just because you have not used your quota doesn't mean that there is available disk).

Even if its showing less then 100% disk utilisation, many filesystems reserve space - typically 5℅ - for superuser/system use only.

Comment: A full disk would indeed be the most obvious, given the listed symptoms. But there are a couple elements that contradict this hypothesis, see edit of OP. Thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: Its still a server - and most likely disk problem.  It is still likely a disk issue. One server may be split among many disks with different users in different disks so others in the same server may not be using the same disk, and a superuser (or log process etc) may have written way more then 100 megs above the 95% threshhold.  Bluehost need to escallate the issue to an administrator to fix the IO subsystem on that server/cluster.